# Cannot implicitly convert type void to IList<int>

Tags: c#, oop

```
 string categoryIDList = Convert.ToString(reader["categoryIDList"]);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryIDList))
    {
        c.CategoryIDList  =
            new List<int>().AddRange(
                categoryIDList 
                    .Split(',')
                    .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)));

    }
```

The class has a property IList CategoryIDList that I am trying to assign to above.

Error:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the [AddRange method of the generic List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(VS.80).aspx) is declared as returning void.

**Update**: Edited to fix `List<int>` vs. `IList<int>` issue.

You need to change it to:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
foo.AddRange(
    categoryIDList 
    .Split(',')
    .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)));
c.CategoryIDList = foo;
```

Comment: Arghh, IList<int> doesn't support AddRange though?  c.CategoryIDList is of type IList<int>

Comment: Yes, this won't compile as-is.

Comment: @homestead & Reed Copsey: Yup, sorry about that.  Simple solution is just to use a temporary variable of type `List<int>`.  See my edit for one possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not initialize the list with the results of your select query instead of doing AddRange since it takes IEnumerable as an overload:

```
c.CategoryIDList = new List<int>(categoryIDList.Split(',')
 .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

AddRange doesn't return a list - it returns void.  You can do this via the constructor for `List<T>` [that takes an enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx):

```
string categoryIDList = Convert.ToString(reader["categoryIDList"]);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryIDList))
{
    c.CategoryIDList  =
        new List<int>(
            categoryIDList.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have better understanding of what is going on, I created example below.
Solution should be based on 1. list.AddRange, 2. then reassigning list to something else:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>{1,4, 8};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 9, 3, 1 };
//this will cause compiler error "AddRange cannot convert source type void to target type List<>"
//List<int> list3 = list1.AddRange(list2); 
//do something like this:
List<int> list3 = new List<int>();
list3.AddRange(list1);
list3.AddRange(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the result of AddRange to c.CategoryIDList, not the new list itself.